# JDialog take time to close around 45 seconds

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have a `MyDialog` which extends `JDialog`, when I close the `MyDialog` it will take a time around 30 - 45 seconds. `MyDialog` is a child form of my main form which is `JFrame` and until `MyDialog` is closed the focus can not come to main window. What will be the reason that `MyDialog` take time to close the dialog?

For close operation I am setting:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell without looking at the code that implements the dialog. If it has threads, or a lot resources, that could be a problem.  I always let my dialog return, and then set the dialog variable to null, so the garbage collector can clear it up for me. How about some code example?

Comment: On a wider note, prefer composition to inheritance.  Don't extend dialog, just use an instance of a standard dialog.

Comment: profile it with jvisualvm or Netbeans profiler.

Comment: Do you show the dialog from an applet?

Answer (score 3):

Almost always problems like this are because you are doing something that takes a long time in the EDT thread.  What do you do after the dialog is closed?  Do you take actions based on the button the user clicked?  Make sure these actions execute quickly or in a new thread.